# Java square number

Tags: java

I don't understand why the output is `25`, from my wrong understanding obviously, i thought it is `20`, because: first loop will be: `i = 2; x = 5` and there will be 4 more  loops since `i <= m` , therefor `5 x 4 = 20`. I know i'm wrong but can't figure out where.

```
public class num {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int m, x, i;

        x = 0;
        i = 1;
        m = 5;

        while (i<= m){
            x = x + m;
            i = i + 1;

        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens with `i` and `x` by printing their values inside the loop?

Comment: **the first loop will be: i = 2; x = 5 and there will be 4 more loops since i <= m**. You are right, but all in all these are 5 loops (not 4) and 5 x 5 = 25.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try a dry-run for this:

```
x=0;i=1;m=5
while (1<=5) ? yes, so x=0+5; i=2,
while (2<=5) ? yes, so x=5+5; i=3,
while (3<=5) ? yes, so x=10+5; i=4,
while (4<=5) ? yes, so x=15+5; i=5,
while (5<=5) ? yes, so x=20+5; i=6,
while (6<=5) ? no, so exit from loop
```

And therefore the result is: `x=25`

Answer (score 0):

Whenver face this type situation, try debugging and printing. Most of the time you'll find your answqer:

```
public class num {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m, x, i;

        x = 0;
        i = 1;
        m = 5;

        System.out.println("Initial : x = " + x + " and i = " + i);

        while (i <= m) {
            x = x + m;
            i = i + 1;
            System.out.println("x = " + x + " and i = " + i);
        }
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Initial : x = 0 and i = 1
x = 5 and i = 2
x = 10 and i = 3
x = 15 and i = 4
x = 20 and i = 5
x = 25 and i = 6
25
```